# restrict user when select from ajax calendar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I had Ajax calendar for birth date on registeration form  and I tried to restrict user from select now date also I tried to limit user to select from calendar birth date equal 6 years or greater than6 years.I user rang validator but I couldnot .So please any one help me.